# MySQL Automatic backup tools

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, mysql

I use [back-in-time](http://backintime.le-web.org/) for backuping up  my projects. but my Database's are not included. I'd like to backup all database's scheduling by day or hours.  Is there any tool to backup MySQL automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL Admin (discontinued - was available in natty) has a backup tool with a (basic) [scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/administrator/en/mysql-administrator-backup-schedule.html) to make backups on a daily, weekly, or monthly basis. It is even included in Ubuntu: [mysql-admin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/mysql-admin).

Random image from the web: [image: im1]

My favourite way ofcourse is command line and I found a [backup script on UF](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8714285&postcount=8).

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script to make a regular copy of a mysql database and gzip it into the SAVEDIR.

USER="authorized_user"
PASSWORD="the_password"
DATABASE="database_name"
SAVEDIR="/backup"

/usr/bin/nice -n 19 /usr/bin/mysqldump -u $USER --password=$PASSWORD --default-character-set=utf8 $DATABASE -c | /usr/bin/nice -n 19 /bin/gzip -9 > $SAVEDIR/$DATABASE-$(date '+%Y%m%d-%H').sql.gz
```

Edit the varibles, save it as .bkup.sh and [run it in a crontab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto), then you have an automatic mysql backup. All the code for this script explained [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8714561&postcount=9). Kudos to kat_ams.

Answer (score 14):

If you're on a server without a GUI, here's a package that will backup and rotate all of your MySQL databases daily by default.

```
sudo apt-get install automysqlbackup
```

That's it. The default configuration is sane so you're done unless you need something special. The backup files will be placed in `/var/lib/automysqlbackup` which you should rsync somewhere off-site.

Comment: You can configure this program in `/etc/default/automysqlbackup` more info available after executing `man automysqlbackup`

Comment: can this transfer backups to a ftp server?

Comment: Yes but like rsync, it's outside the scope of this backup utility. You'll have to write a script to do it