# Backup of MySQL database

Tags: mysql, backup

Since I'm just a beginner in using Ubuntu 18.04 and MySQL 5.7 on it, which is the best and fastest way to do *backup of database using terminal*? Or do I need to search for it in some files and whatever...

Comment: Here is how to automatically backup mysql : https://askubuntu.com/a/223709/454520

Answer (score 0):

The default method would be to use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html).

```
mysqldump -u {user} -p {database} > {backup.sql}
```

and you will get a text based file that holds any SQL related to that that database: table definition, content. The link will list far more options (you can for instance only dump the structure of the database, include procedures, functions and many more)